# Prove or Disprove that $f(x)$ cannot be $C_3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Consider a function $y=f(x)$ with a single argument *x* with the real number line as its domain. Fix a real number $Q>0$, and suppose the following:

$f(x)=f'(x)=f''(x)=0$ for all *x* from the interval $(0,Q]$

$f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$ for all $x>Q$

Question: can $f(x)$ be a three times continuously differentiable $(C_3)$ function?

Note: if you want to give a counter-example, please find one that is not a piecewise function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x\le1\\{}\\(x-1)^4,&x>1\end{cases}$$

fulfills the conditions and it is $\;C^3\;$ in the whole real line:

$$f_+'(1)=\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{(x-1)^4}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1+}(x-1)^3=0$$

$$f_+''(1)=\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{f'(x)-f'(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{4(x-1)^3}{x-1}=0$$

$$f_+'''(1)=\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{f''(x)-f''(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{12(x-1)^2}{x-1}=0$$

All the left derivatives above at $\;x=1\;$ are clearly zero.

Comment: Why did you choose $(x-1)^4$ not $(x-1)^2$?

Comment: @Asemismaiel Because...It is just the first thing I thought of.

Comment: Thanks, could you give a counter-example that is not a piecewise function?

Comment: @KeithChan Most probably not. Right now I can't, and I suspect that if I could it'd be a terrible, horrible-looking function.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a function which is $C^{\infty}$ and satisfies those conditions. 
\begin{align}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & x\leq 1 \\ e^{-\frac{1}{x-1}} & x>1 \end{array}\right.
\end{align}
We can show that $f^{(n)}(1)=0$ for all $n\geq 1$.